# How to get local density field of a compressible solid Neo-Hookean material undergoing large deformation?

Tags: elasticity, continuum-mechanics, non-linear-systems

My understanding of a compressible material in the context of non-linear elasticity in continuum mechanics is that the volume of the body can change due to the applied forces. Due to the law of conservation of mass, the total mass of the body is fixed. So, if the volume changes the density should also change. But is it possible to find the density field? Or because we are treating the material as continuum we only get one global value of density?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can find the density field. It is given by the determinant of the  deformation gradient ($\mathbf{F}$) in the following expression

$$\rho_t (x) |\mathbf{F}| = \rho_0(x)\, ,$$

where $\rho_t$ refers to the density in the deformed configuration and $\rho_0$ in the original one. You could take a look at reference 1.

#### References

1. Bigoni, D. (2012). Nonlinear solid mechanics: bifurcation theory and material instability. Cambridge University Press.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question and for giving the reference!